Extract dollar value from another sheet, sum in data sheet when value matches another
Unable to get values to sum.
I can extract the values with:
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A:A, "\$(\d+.\d+|\d+)")*1))
But I am not able to match them. In the images below, I want column D1 to pull all $ values from A:A, if the value in column B on Sheet1 matches the name in column A on sheet2, total the $ values indexed and print them into column D



Try this out:
=SUM(FILTER(--REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A:A,"\$([\d,]+)"),Sheet1!B:B=A2))

Or a single formula for the whole column:
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(name,IF(name="",,
   SUM(FILTER(--REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A:A,"\$([\d,]+)"),Sheet1!B:B=name)))))

You could also do this with SUMPRODUCT
Dragdown
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A:A,"\$([\d,]+)"),Sheet1!B:B=A2)

Autofill
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(name,IF(name="",,
   SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A:A,"\$([\d,]+)"),Sheet1!B:B=name))))


that multiplication what you are doing at the end *1 you can replace it with result of boolean logic as Sheet1!B2:B=A2 will output either TRUE or FALSE which is 1 or 0
=SORT(IFNA((Sheet1!B2:B=A2)*REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A2:A, "\$(?: )?([\d,.]+)")))


for sum:
=SORT(SUM(IFNA((Sheet1!B2:B=A2)*REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A2:A, "\$(?: )?([\d,.]+)"))))


